Adjustment in DLNM - case control setting
I have data in a case-control format with a 5-year lag of exposure. I want to adjust, in addition to the strata, for the number of monitoring stations used to calculate the exposure. The problem is that the OR increases to millions after the adjustment, which does not make sense. I tried 3 different degrees of freedom.
for (i in c(3,4,5)) {
### cross basis
cbnest <- crossbasis(DF_for_dlnm, lag = c(1,5),argvar=list("bs",degree=2,df=i),
                            arglag=list(fun="bs",knots=c(1,2),intercept=F))

### conditional logistic regression model
mnest <- clogit(Group ~ cbnest + Temp_stations_n + strata(subclass), data)
AIC <- extractAIC(mnest)
pnest <- crosspred(cbnest, mnest, cen=0, at=0:30*1)

### plots 
paste("AIC = ",round(AIC[2]),", Degrees of freedom = ",i)
plot(pnest, zlab="OR", xlab="Temperature (°C)", ylab="Lag (years)")
plot(pnest, lag=1, ylab="OR at lag 1", xlab="Temperature (°C)",xlim=c(15,23), ylim=c(0.5,1.5), cex.names=1.25, cex.axis=1.25, cex.lab=1.25)
}



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am looking for an explanation for these abnormal results. 'Temp_stations_n' includes the number of stations. 'data' is the original dataset, which consists of a row per patient, with 'Group' representing whether it is a case or control.
